# Finding unkown function

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I want to find a function `t3`

```
t3[x1, x2, x3]
```

that fulfills these equations:

```
2 D[t3[x1, x2, x3], x3] + 6 D[t3[x1, x2, x3], x2] - 9 x2^2 D[t3[x1, x2, x3], x1] !=0
```

for any real x

```
D[t3[x1, x2, x3], x3] + 3 D[t3[x1, x2, x3], x2] + 
    (-1 - 9/2 x1^2) D[t3[x1, x2, x3], x1] == 0
```

How can I do this (with *Mathematica*)?

A simpler example

[image]

Comment: The `!=` means that the expression should not be identically equal to zero, or it should for no values `x1, x2, x3` take the value zero?

Comment: it means that the expression should never be 0 for any real x1,x2,x3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first solve the equation:

```
sol[x1_, x2_, x3_] = 
 t3[x1, x2, x3] /. 
  DSolve[D[t3[x1, x2, x3], x3] + 
       3 D[t3[x1, x2, x3], x2] + (-1 - 9/2 x1^2) D[t3[x1, x2, x3], x1] == 0, 
        t3[x1, x2, x3], {x1, x2, x3}][[1]]
```

[image]

`C[1]` here is an **arbitrary** function of **two** variables.

Let's take the second condition:

```
sol2[x1_, x2_, x3_] = 
 FullSimplify[
  D[sol[x1, x2, x3], x3] + 6 D[sol[x1, x2, x3], x2] - 9 x2^2 D[sol[x1, x2, x3], x1]
 ]
```

[image]

Now, I'm not sure what is `!=` supposed to mean: for the expression to not be identically equal to zero, or to never attain the value zero? If the former, then with

```
f[a_, b_] := a^2 + b^2
```

for example

```
sol2[1, 1, 1] /. C[1] -> f // N
```

> 3.71851

so the expression is not identically zero. Thence, the solution is

```
sol[x1, x2, x3] /. C[1] -> f
```

[image]

Here

```
FindInstance[sol2[x1, x2, x3] == 0 /. C[1] -> f, {x1, x2, x3}, Reals]
```

> {{x1 -> 0, x2 -> 0, x3 -> 0}}

---

On the other hand, if `C[1] == ArcTan`, then

```
sol2[1, 1, 1] /. C[1] -> ArcTan // N
```

> -0.365403

so the solution is not identically equal to zero. Moreover,

```
FindInstance[sol2[x1, x2, x3] == 0 /. C[1] -> ArcTan, {x1, x2, x3}, Reals]
```

didn't give any instance for several minutes, so it's likely there is none and the function is non-zero everywhere.